# How to get the table tag of an .msg file?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, msg

I already get the html code of my msg file as text. Now I want to get only the table tag of that html file and put it on my default.aspx div tag.

I have already tried:

```
div1.InnerText = (trimmed html code of msg file);
```

and

```
div1.InnerHTML = (trimmed html code of msg file);
```